# Serializing JSON using c#

Tags: c#, json, wcf, json.net

I am working on some App. in which I want to send data from my server to Android Application in JSON. I have a `RestFul WCF service` from which my Client communicates with server. Its fine if I want a single value.. but im struck when I want a Bunch of data. I have searched some threads and studied about the JSON.net dectionary and an object but I didn't find any simple example. Will appreciate if someone give me the Head start or sort out my problem.

here is an example How I'm trying .

**DATABASE**
[image]

Now what I want? I want all that results which has `q_QuizCode` = **dfsew43** in JSON string or an Object format.

**How I try:**

```
public GetQuiz getAllQuiz(string q_code)
    {
        GetQuiz getQuizObject = new GetQuiz();
        List<GetQuiz> gQuiz = new List<GetQuiz>();

        #region DataBase_Connectivity

        string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQL"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
        conn.Open();

        #endregion

        string query = "select q_Question,q_opa,q_opb,q_opc,q_opd,q_cop from Table_QuizDetail where q_QuizCode = @qcode";
        SqlCommand oCmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qcode", q_code);
        using (SqlDataReader oReader = oCmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (oReader.Read())
            {

                getQuizObject.Quiz_Question = oReader["q_Question"].ToString();
                getQuizObject.Quiz_Option_A = oReader["q_opa"].ToString();
                getQuizObject.Quiz_Option_B = oReader["q_opb"].ToString();
                getQuizObject.Quiz_Option_C = oReader["q_opc"].ToString();
                getQuizObject.Quiz_Option_D = oReader["q_opd"].ToString();
                getQuizObject.Quiz_Correct_Op = oReader["q_cop"].ToString();

                gQuiz.Add(getQuizObject);
            }
        }
  }
```

**What I get:**

```
{
"getAllQuizResult":{
 "Quiz_Correct_Op":"b",
"Quiz_Option_A":"jreowi",
"Quiz_Option_B":"slkj",
"Quiz_Option_C":"elk",
"Quiz_Option_D":"dslkj",
"Quiz_Question":"ewepewoirpowejrdsngfdglfdjkbk"}
}
```

this is what I actually got Just a Last traversed ROW in database.

Comment: If this is a fairly serious project, I strongly advice to you to have a look at an ORM (Object Relational Mapper) which will do all the complicated, error-prone SQL parsing for your and serve you nice, tidy objects that you can work with instead. I would guess that the two most common ones are [Entity Framework](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/) and [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to instantiate new GetQuiz object inside the while loop, just like Patrick is stating.

But the method should also return `List<GetQuiz>` instead of just `GetQuiz`.

Change the method signature to

```
public List<GetQuiz> getAllQuiz(string q_code)
```

and add

```
return gQuiz
```

as the last statement in the method, otherwise it won't compile anyway.

Answer (score 2):

That is because you don't instantiate the `getQuizObject` object again when iterating. Therefore it keeps changing the values of the original `getQuizObject` object.

Try this:

```
while (oReader.Read())
{
    GetQuiz getQuizObject = new GetQuiz();

    ...

    gQuiz.Add(getQuizObject);
}
```